# Call Sauls phone number seems real?

Tags: better-call-saul

In season 3 episode 5 in the opening credits there is a shot of a bus bench with a Better Call Saul and the phone number is (505) 503-4455, instead of a 555 number, anyone ever call Saul?

Comment: Most of the phone numbers in BCS are real...at least according to Reddit.

Answer (score 6):

So after I started the question I just decided to call Saul. 
Yes this is a valid phone number, it is very cute what you hear when you call it.

You can hear the message at :

Comment: Let me guess... The assistant must have picked the call? :D