# Whose phone numbers are shared in Indian Movies?

Tags: dialogue, indian-cinema

Many of the Indian movies contain dialogues which include phone number (of valid number of digits) shared with another character as per requirement in that movie.

I want to know, Whose number they use to share? Do they use random public number?

For **example**: In [Maroon](https://www.netflix.com/watch/80159668?trackId=13752289&tctx=0%2C0%2Caba13ce2e10418624bb6c64ca80348ce0e48899c%3Afe5cd7cab95fd71a5c4c4b3febf7f862e6c4531f%2C%2C), Police is sharing his mobile number to main character.

**Question:** Whose number actually these people are sharing in movies?.

Comment: Either it is a number setup by the film company, or it is a generic non-existing number. Answering for just *any* number is therefore not possible. [Searching the site for 'phone number'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=phone+number+is%3Aq) gives you several questions about the 555 phone numbers, or about specific movies.

Comment: Please, *please* do not dial random numbers you see in movies or TV shows. There are documented instances, like the one you found, where real numbers were used by mistake and the poor sap who owned it got bombarded with hundreds of phone calls.

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85628/why-always-555

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options here.

- Whenever you see a (US) phone number starting with 555, it doesn't exist. There's a convention in filmmaking where 555 is used for fictional phone numbers.
- Sometimes, the production company uses a real phone number, and when you call it, you get to hear an easter egg (e.g. as if you were listening to the voicemail of the actual character)
- There are cases of movies using phone numers that went to real people. This has commonly ended in lawsuits because the owners of the phone number get harassed by callers. This is the driving force behind the convention of using 555 for fictional numbers.

Comment: I think you need to update your answer according to new state of the question